# How can I select the first time a number shows up in more than one column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table of flights, which have an origin and destination city, represented as a foreign id.

A very simplified example of this table looks like:

```
id | origin | destination
023      1        3
044      3        2
332      2        1
509      1        3
493      1        4
```

I need to get the first time that a city shows up as an origin or a destination; a list of all the flights that contain a city that hasn't been flown to or from yet.

What I would like to get for the above example would be:

```
023: 1, 3
044: 2 
493: 4
```

Flights 332 and 509 aren't in the output because they only visit cities that have already been visited.

Here's what I've tried:

```
(SELECT distinct(origin), distinct(destination) FROM flights ORDER BY id)
```

Doesn't work because you can't select more than one distinct column

```
SELECT (distinct(origin) FROM flights ORDER BY id) UNION (distinct (destination) FROM flights ORDER BY id)
```

Doesn't work because of syntax errors, but mainly because it doesn't take into account that a city should be unique in the origin *and* destination columns.

If there's not a quick way to do this in SQL I'm also happy to just iterate through and keep track of cities that have been visited (this app has literally one user, and he doesn't care about a few milliseconds of computation because he's over 80), but I'd love to know just so that I can learn more about SQL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(city ORDER BY city) cities
FROM (
    SELECT city, min(id) id
    FROM (
        SELECT origin city, MIN(id) id
        FROM flights
        GROUP BY city

        UNION

        SELECT destination city, MIN(id) id
        FROM flights
        GROUP BY city) u
    GROUP BY city) x
GROUP BY id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5bd5/3)

Comment: Wow! That's quite the query. It's so strange what is easy and what is difficult in SQL :)